# React passing function as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i'm using typescript/react and i have this function from a class based component A:

```
    listUpdateFunction() {
        console.log("called update functions")
        this.setState({ shouldUpdate: true });
    }
```

which i am passing through  as an prop to another component B. And using it for a submit button.

```
<button type="submit" onClick={this.props.listUpdateFunction}>Submit!</button>
```

My prop interface for class B is:

```
interface IProps {
    listUpdateFunction: Function;
}
```

I plan on using this function to call componentDidUpdate in class A. However my code doesn't compile for class B it says

> (JSX attribute) React.DOMAttributes.onClick?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined

Which I don't understand, reading this error message I'd assume that the function could be undefined but i think the interface would guarantee that it isn't null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your interface

```
interface IProps {
    listUpdateFunction: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}
```